# Why won't my MediaPlayer methods work when moved into a class?

Tags: android, class

I have some methods to play sounds in MainActivity.

They look like this and they work fine.

```
public void hydrogen(){
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hydrogen);
        mp.start();
    }
```

I thought I'd move them into a class, so I can use the methods in other activities.

This is what I have in the class:

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

```
public class Sounds {

     void hydrogen(){
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hydrogen);
        mp.start();
           }
   
}
```

I get red underlines under "this" and R.raw.hydrogen.

The lines under hydrogen go away when I make the method static, but I can't get rid of the lines under "this".

What have I done wrong?

The error message is:

> Cannot resolve method 'create(com.xxmassdeveloper.lrwhack2.Sounds, int)'

Comment: If a method is made static, then in any OO language, `this` (or its equivalent) ceases to have any meaning. It only represents an instance if it is called in an instance context.

Answer (score 2):

First parameter of `MediaPlayer.create(Context context, int resid)` consumes `Context`.

If you look into `Activity` class, it extends `Context`. Therefore within the functions of your `Activity` class, you can use `this`, and it refers to the `Activity` class you are at.

And for your class `Sounds`, it is just a simple class without relationship with `Context`. So you need to pass `Context` into this class, like following:

```java
public class Sound {
    // Create a local variable Context so that you can access it in functions of this Class
    private Context context;

    // Create a constructor with Context
    public Sound(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    void hydrogen() {
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.colors);
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

And then you can make use of the passed `Context` for your function.

Comment: Thanks.  The red underlines are gone, but my program crashes when I try call the method.  I couldn't fit all the code here, so I started a new thread.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75252388/why-cant-i-call-this-method-from-a-class